# How to properly take a boost::optional<std::chrono::duration> as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, boost, c++-chrono

I need to have a function accept a `boost::optional<std::chrono::duration>`.
I would like to be able to pass it, for example, either `std::chrono::milliseconds`, `std::chrono::seconds`, or `boost::none`.

I have a couple of solutions which do not exactly achieve what I want.

**Attempt 1:**

```
template <class PeriodT>
void foo(boost::optional<std::chrono::duration<int64_t, PeriodT>> duration);
```

**Problems with attempt 1:**

I cannot simply pass an `std::chrono::duration` or even `boost::none`. To pass `boost::none` I have to do the following:

```
boost::optional<std::chrono::seconds> input = boost::none;
foo(input);
```

I cannot call

```
foo(boost::none);
```

or

```
std::chrono::seconds input(10);
foo(input);
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
void foo(boost::optional<std::chrono::milliseconds> duration);
```

**Problems with attempt 2:**

Automatic conversion won't happen.

```
foo(std::chrono::seconds(10));
```

Will not compile.

```
foo(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
```

Will compile, and so will

```
foo(boost::none);
```

Is there any way I can have a function cleanly accept a `boost::optional`
of any rep/period?

The function in my actual use case will need to accept multiple of these optional durations, so default values won't work for me.

Comment: Just use overloads?

Comment: @o11c How does this solve my problem? Are you suggesting I define overloads for every `std::chrono::duration` period I would want to use?

Comment: You probably don't need any concrete durations other than `std::chrono::nanoseconds` - all the others will convert since it's lossless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include "boost/optional.hpp"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void foo(boost::optional<std::chrono::milliseconds> duration)
{
    if (duration)
        std::cout << duration->count() << "ms\n";
    else
        std::cout << "none\n";
}

void foo(std::chrono::milliseconds duration)
{
    foo(boost::optional<std::chrono::milliseconds>{duration});
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    foo(10ms);
    foo(10s);
    foo(boost::none);
}
```

If you want to accept *any* `chrono::duration<Rep, Period>`, you need to add one more overload and template everything.  Also you need to decide what `Rep` and `Period` you want to default to for `boost::none`:

```
#include "boost/optional.hpp"
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

template <class Rep, class Period>
void foo(boost::optional<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>> duration)
{
    using date::operator<<;
    if (duration)
        std::cout << *duration << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "none\n";
}

template <class Rep, class Period>
void foo(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> duration)
{
    foo(boost::optional<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>>{duration});
}

void foo(boost::none_t)
{
    foo(boost::optional<std::chrono::seconds>{});
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    foo(10ms);
    foo(10s);
    foo(boost::none);
}
```

Above I've also used [Howard's date lib](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) for easier printing of the arbitrary durations:

```
10ms
10s
none
```

Comment: How could this easily be extended for a function which takes two optional durations? i.e. `foo(std::chrono::seconds(10), boost::none)`, `foo(boost::none, std::chrono::seconds(10))`, or `foo(std::chrono::seconds(10), std::chrono::milliseconds(10))`

Comment: You would need to use templates constrained with SFINEA.  It's a lot messier, but it can avoid the O(N^2) problem.  Personally I would just pick a value out of the duration (such as `duration::min()`) that has the semantics of `none` instead of fooling around with `optional`.

Comment: AANAE (Anagrams Are Not An Error) :)

Comment: <big laugh>  I can't spell English words, much less unpronounceable acronyms! :-)